# How to have generic typescript props in react? Typescript generic props don't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Here's what I'm trying to do in react,

I've got a functional component where I pass down 1 prop

```
<TableComponent tableStateProp={tableState} />
```

tableState is a state hook in the parent component

```
  const [tableState, setTableState] = useState<TableState<string[]>>();
```

the table state type is defined inside of my table component

```
export type TableState<T> = {
  pagination: {
    limit: number,
    skip: number,
  }
  data: T[];
  columns: string[],
}
```

But here is where my problem starts, ideally I would be able to do this

```
const TableComponent: React.FC<{
  tableState: TableState<T>;
}> = ({tableState}) => {
```

But I get an error saying `TS2304: Cannot find name 'T'.`

I know for a generic prop function the syntax is something like `function<T>(): type<T>`
but what is it for a generic prop/object?

Edit: I am using this component elsewhere where data is not a string[], hence why I'm trying to make it generic

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `React.FC<>`. Declare your component as a named function and you can add the generic `<T>`.

```
export type TableState<T> = {
  pagination: {
    limit: number;
    skip: number;
  };
  data: T[];
  columns: string[];
};

function TableComponent<T>({
  tableState,
}: React.PropsWithChildren<{
  tableState: TableState<T>;
}>) {
  // ...
}
```

If you don't need the `children` prop to work, you don't need to use `React.PropsWithChildren` either, just:

```
function TableComponent<T>({ tableState }: { tableState: TableState<T> }) {
```

If you want to be explicit about the return typing right at the `TableComponent` level (and not when you use it in your app later on), you can [peek at what `React.FC` is doing](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/5330c85e63e4f782dd598364bc13b1039eac7a83/types/react/index.d.ts#L539-L545) and type explicitly accordingly:

```
function TableComponent<T>({
  tableState,
}: {
  tableState: TableState<T>;
}): ReactElement<any, any> | null {
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Is there not a way to achieve this with const functions rather than named functions?

Answer (score 0):

You need update like this:

```
const TableComponent: React.FC<{
  tableState: TableState<string[]>;
}>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention I need it to be generic, I'm using this component elsewhere where data is not a string[]